# What is the intuitive reason why Ampere's law is incorrect?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, conservation-laws, maxwell-equations

I don't understand why Ampere's Law for magnetic fields is wrong. So initially, we got taught it as the following:

$$\vec\nabla\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\vec{J}$$

and this turns out to be wrong. I also understand there is something to do with a continuity equation, such as:

$$-\vec\nabla\cdot\vec{j}=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}$$

which in the case I know it tells us that the flow of particles in some region is equal to the flow outwards. I can see how this applies to charge separately from any other equation.

As far as I can tell Ampere's Law does not 'work' as there is a lack of charge conservation, however, I cannot understand why this is the case. I've also seen the derivation of the new form which involves the following equation:

$$\oint_S\vec{J}\cdot d\vec{S}\space +\int_V\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}d^3x=0$$

but again, I don't understand why this is the case. It seems  to me, at least, that the following equation is sort of derived backwards if that makes sense:

$$\vec\nabla\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}$$

Despite seeing all of this, I still don't understand why the original form of Ampere's law violates the conservation of charge. It may be a case of me not putting the pieces together but I don't know. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the continuity equation should be $-\vec\nabla\cdot\vec{J}=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}$ (i.e., it involves the divergence of $\vec{J}$, not its curl.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer already shows that [Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) and
[charge conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation) in their differential forms
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\vec{J}$$
$$-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}$$
are contradicting each other.

---

However, the differential form of these equations are not so
easy to visualize, especially if you are new to differential calculus.
The integral form of these equations are much more intuitive.
So let us repeat the reasoning using the equations in their integral form.

The [integral form of Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law#Explanation) is
$$\oint_C \vec{B}\ d\vec{\ell}=\mu_0 I \tag{1}$$
It means, the line integral of the magnetic field $\vec{B}$
along a closed line $C$
is equal to the current $I$ enclosed by this line.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Hyperphysics - Ampere's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/amplaw.html))</sub>

Now imagine, you stretch the enclosed area, so that its boundary
line gets smaller and smaller, until this line has shrinked
to a point and the open area has become a closed area.

[image]

Then, in (1) the line integral on the left side becomes zero
(because the line is only a point now).
And $I$ on the right side becomes the net current through the closed surface
(counting outgoing current as positive and incoming current as negative).
$$0=\mu_0 I \tag{2}$$

This is obviously in contradiction with the [charge conservation law
(in its integral form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation#Formal_statement_of_the_law) for the enclosed volume
$$-\frac{dQ}{dt}=I \tag{3}$$
which says that the net current $I$ leaving the surface of the volume must
be equal to the decreasing rate of the charge $Q$ enclosed by this surface.

Comment: You're right it's far easier to understand in this regard. Only thing I'm still confused about - everything else is cleared up - is if you shrink the enclosing curve C to a point, this is 1D in nature and so how could a current be passing through it, or is that the wrong way of thinking about this? Again, everything else is stellar and completely cleared up the confusion, you hero

Comment: @NehalPatel When you deform the first image to the second image,
then the point (actually the small closed curve in the second image)
"encloses" all the rest of the grey surface, i.e. where the current 
$I$ passes through.

Comment: Ah got it, again thank you so much!

Comment: You're assuming analytic fields, but there's no mathematical requirement for this. We only use that assumption because it leads to models that match experiment.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mathematical fact that the divergence of the curl of a vector field is always zero.  I'm not sure whether one can give an "intuitive reason" for this or not, but it is in fact true.

This means that if we take the divergence of both sides of the original form of Ampère's law, we find that we must have
$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \vec{\nabla} \cdot (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B}) = 0.
$$
But since the continuity equation is
$$
\vec\nabla\cdot\vec{J}=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}
$$
then the original form of Ampère's Law can only hold if
$$
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = 0.
$$
In other words, the original form of Ampère's Law cannot hold if both of the following things are true:

1. The continuity equation holds (i.e. charge is conserved.)
2. The charge density is changing at any point in space.

Comment: It's only a mathematical fact for analytic fields, where the divergence and curl are well behaved. Nature is under no obligation to obey this, or any other mathematical rule. However, the hypothesis that the fields are analytic produced testable results which turned out to conform to experiment.

Comment: Ah ok, this is making more sense now. Cheers